# What is the absolute easiest way to add back/forward/bookmark support to an existing Jquery/AJAX website?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm a new bie with JavaScript and JQuery but I have navigation working. I've read several tutorials and threads about implementing history and bookmarks but they all overestimate my knowledge of JS. Is there a more basic way to implement it that doesn't involve page upon page of iframes and php? I'm trying to learn without diving in way over my head.

html:

```
<ul id="navigation">        
<li> <a class="nbutton" href="12.html"> a </a> </li>
<li> <a class="nbutton" href="23.html"> b </a> </li>
<li> <a class="nbutton" href="34.html"> c </a> </li>
<li> <a class="nbutton" href="45.html"> d </a> </li>
<li> <a class="nbutton" href="56.html"> e </a> </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
$.ajaxSetup 
({ cache: false });

$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(".nbutton").click(function(){
        $("#content").load($(this).attr("href"));
        return false;
    });
});         
</script>
```

Comment: https://github.com/balupton/History.js/

Comment: Including those files simply makes my page fade to black when I click a link. Am I doing something incorrect by simply including them? https://gist.github.com/854622

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I'd guess you have to include the bundled  `jquery.history.js` file after jQuery for it to work.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4rRzyk5b - This is the current includes and script I'm using, and from what I read the history code isn't strictly HTML5 so I should be fine with it, but it refuses to work correctly.

Comment: This doesn't happen on IE8, only Firefox.

Comment: Correction. IE8 doesn't bug out but doesn't offer forward/backward/bookmark, Firefox offers forward/backward but fades out the entire screen to black when you click a link. The page is still there, if you know where the links are you can click them, but the window is completely black.